# Sum quantity only when certain products

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a SQL that select orders based on specific products, however when I add a SUM column to measure the quantity it also gives me the count of products that are in the order that I don´t need. For example:

```
ORDER | PRODUCT | QTD
 200      A        1
 200      B        1
 200      C        1
```

So I only want to sum the product A.

Is it possible to make an SQL like this ?

```
SELECT SUM(QTD) WHEN PRODUCT LIKE A
```

Appreciate any help on this matter

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE PRODUCT = 'A'`.  You should show your original query.

Comment: You can use where clause SELECT SUM(QTD) WHERE PRODUCT = 'A';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `case` expression inside the `sum()` function

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN PRODUCT = 'A' THEN QTD ELSE 0 END) 
. . .
```

However, this would produce result set with all `PRODUCT`s but it will do the sum only when `PRODUCT = 'A'` other will be `0`.